# How to restrict add media library only to images of the same post family?

Tags: wp-query, attachments, media

So when I am creating a post, I would like to only be able to see images (after clicking ,add media above wp editor) that have been uploaded and attached to posts of the same family of the current post i'm creating.

My current code does not seem to work.

```
global $post;

$parentID = $post->post_parent; //Shows 2068
$currID = $post->ID; //Shows 2069

$args = array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'projects', 'numberposts' => -1  );
        $children = get_children($args);

        foreach ($children as $child):
            $childIDs .= " ".$child->ID; //Get Children IDs
        endforeach;

$allIDs = $parentID." ".$currID.$childIDs; //shows 2068 2069 2070 2071

add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'wpb_show_current_user_attachments');

function wpb_show_current_user_attachments( $query, $allIDs ) {

    $allIDarray = explode (" ", $allIDs); 
    //$user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( $user_id && !current_user_can('activate_plugins') && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {

        // $query['author'] = $user_id;
        $query['post_parent'] = $allIDarray;

    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Can you ellaborate further what you mean by family? Is that a custom taxonomy? Where have you put your code?

Comment: @TomJNowell Well my post family is Parent/Child/GrandChild.. When I upload any images within the family, I just wanted to show those images as choices when I click add Media.

Comment: There's only one parameter that [`ajax_query_attachments_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/ajax_query_attachments_args/) sends to its callbacks. And what are those code above the `add_filter()`? They should be in the callback.

Comment: this is close to what I am trying to do, but I wanted to add more family posts IDs dynamically: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156319/filter-media-library-by-author-or-post-parent?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the query using `posts_where` and `posts_join` filters.

```
function restrict_media_images_per_post_type($query) {
    add_filter('posts_where', 'media_posts_where');
    add_filter('posts_join', 'media_posts_join');
    return $query;
}
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', 'restrict_media_images_per_post_type');
```

Change "WHERE" clause to restrict to specific post type to which selected post belongs to

```
function media_posts_where($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_id = false;
    $whitelist_post_type = array(
        'post',
        '{custom post type}' //change this according to your need e.g. projects
    );
    if ( isset($_POST['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if ( $post && in_array($post->post_type, $whitelist_post_type)) {
            $where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND my_post_parent.post_type = %s ", $post->post_type);
            //$where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND my_post_parent.post_type = %s AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_parent = %d", $post->post_type, $_POST['post_id']);  //Use this if you want to restrict to selected post only
        }
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Change "JOIN" clause to get media by restricting to the post parent

```
function media_posts_join($join) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( isset($_POST['post_id']) ) {
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} as my_post_parent ON ({$wpdb->posts}.post_parent = my_post_parent.ID) ";
    }
    return $join;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!! :) Final Code:

```
function wpse156319_posts_where( $where, $query ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $currentID = $_POST['post_id']; //shows 2069
    $post = get_post($currentID); //shows 2068
    $parentID = $post->post_parent;
    $chargs = array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'projects' );
    $children = get_children($chargs);


    $where .= ' AND (';

    if($children):
        foreach ($children as $child):
            $where .= $wpdb->posts . '.post_parent = '.$child->ID.' OR ';
        endforeach;
    endif;

    if($parentID):
        $where .= $wpdb->posts . '.post_parent = '.$parentID.' OR ';
    endif;

    $where .= $wpdb->posts . '.post_parent = '.$currentID;

    $where .= ')';

    return $where;

}

add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'filterMediaLibrary', 10, 2 );

function filterMediaLibrary($query = array()) {

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse156319_posts_where', 10, 2 );

    return $query;

}
```

Comment: Actually, you can do it without having to use the `posts_where` filter (or without having to write custom SQL) - see this [example](https://gist.github.com/5ally/8bf81e6b9e2fad05440a16b2d5137615) where I used [`get_post_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_ancestors/) to get the post's parent, grandpa, great grandpa, etc.